# How to interpret the warnings: "No tuning parameters" and "All models failed" in Tidymodels workflowsets

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidyverse, tidymodels, r-recipes

I am running into some warnings and errors when trying to run (tune) my workflowsets with the `workflowsets` package from `tidymodels`:

```
i   No tuning parameters. `fit_resamples()` will be attempted
i  1 of 30 resampling: normalized_lm
✓  1 of 30 resampling: normalized_lm (3s)
i  2 of 30 tuning:     normalized_glm
Warning: All models failed. See the `.notes` column.
x  2 of 30 tuning:     normalized_glm failed with: There were no valid metrics for the ANOVA model.
i   No tuning parameters. `fit_resamples()` will be attempted
i  3 of 30 resampling: normalized_knn
Warning: All models failed. See the `.notes` column.
x  3 of 30 resampling: normalized_knn failed with preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1 (predictions): Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `.row`.ℹ `.row = orig_rows`.ℹ `.row` must be size 710 or 1, not 723.
i  4 of 30 tuning:     normalized_svm
Warning: All models failed. See the `.notes` column.
x  4 of 30 tuning:     normalized_svm failed with: There were no valid metrics for the ANOVA model.
i  5 of 30 tuning:     normalized_RF
i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry
Warning: All models failed. See the `.notes` column.
x  5 of 30 tuning:     normalized_RF failed with: There were no valid metrics for the ANOVA model.
i  6 of 30 tuning:     normalized_XGB
i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry
✓  6 of 30 tuning:     normalized_XGB (40.8s)
i   No tuning parameters. `fit_resamples()` will be attempted
i  7 of 30 resampling: rm_corr_lm
✓  7 of 30 resampling: rm_corr_lm (2.5s)
i  8 of 30 tuning:     rm_corr_glm
Warning: All models failed. See the `.notes` column.
x  8 of 30 tuning:     rm_corr_glm failed with: There were no valid metrics for the ANOVA model.
i   No tuning parameters. `fit_resamples()` will be attempted
i  9 of 30 resampling: rm_corr_knn
Warning: All models failed. See the `.notes` column.
x  9 of 30 resampling: rm_corr_knn failed with preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1 (predictions): Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `.row`.ℹ `.row = orig_rows`.ℹ `.row` must be size 710 or 1, not 723.
i 10 of 30 tuning:     rm_corr_svm
Warning: All models failed. See the `.notes` column.
x 10 of 30 tuning:     rm_corr_svm failed with: There were no valid metrics for the ANOVA model.
i 11 of 30 tuning:     rm_corr_RF
i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry
Warning: All models failed. See the `.notes` column.

[...]
```

---

The code:

**STEP 1: Getting the data**

Unfortunately, there is no more space for me to add the data here. I can inform you that the data is

```
> str(ml.data.no.outliers.wf)
tibble [4,519 × 44] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ PrName               : Factor w/ 25 levels "Parklands","Agroforestry Pruning-Organic Fertilizer",..: 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 ...
 $ Out.SubInd           : Factor w/ 42 levels "Biomass Yield",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 ...
 $ Product              : Factor w/ 16 levels "Pearl Millet",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Site.Type            : Factor w/ 3 levels "Farm","Station",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Tree                 : Factor w/ 105 levels "Faidherbia albida",..: 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Out.SubInd.Code      : Factor w/ 42 levels "BiY","SOC","SN",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 ...
 $ Latitude             : num [1:4519] 13.4 13.4 13.5 13.5 13.5 ...
 $ Longitude            : num [1:4519] 2.27 2.27 2.58 2.58 2.58 ...
 $ Bio01_MT_Annu        : num [1:4519] 27.3 27.3 19.4 19.4 19.4 ...
 $ Bio02_MDR            : num [1:4519] 11.2 11.2 12.1 12.1 12.1 ...
 $ Bio03_Iso            : num [1:4519] 64.3 64.3 39.8 39.8 39.8 ...
 $ Bio04_TS             : num [1:4519] 171 171 666 666 666 ...
 $ Bio05_TWM            : num [1:4519] 36.7 36.7 35.9 35.9 35.9 ...
 $ Bio06_MinTCM         : num [1:4519] 19.3 19.3 5.46 5.46 5.46 ...
 $ Bio07_TAR            : num [1:4519] 17.4 17.4 30.4 30.4 30.4 ...
 $ Bio08_MT_WetQ        : num [1:4519] 25.3 25.3 15.8 15.8 15.8 ...
 $ Bio09_MT_DryQ        : num [1:4519] 27.8 27.8 27.6 27.6 27.6 ...
 $ Bio10_MT_WarQ        : num [1:4519] 29.7 29.7 27.7 27.7 27.7 ...
 $ Bio11_MT_ColQ        : num [1:4519] 25.3 25.3 11.5 11.5 11.5 ...
 $ Bio12_Pecip_Annu     : num [1:4519] 1230 1230 195 195 195 ...
 $ Bio13_Precip_WetM    : num [1:4519] 248 248 26.3 26.3 26.3 ...
 $ Bio14_Precip_DryM    : num [1:4519] 1.78 1.78 1.31 1.31 1.31 ...
 $ Bio15_Precip_S       : num [1:4519] 90.7 90.7 48.5 48.5 48.5 ...
 $ Bio16_Precip_WetQ    : num [1:4519] 695.1 695.1 69.2 69.2 69.2 ...
 $ Bio17_Precip_DryQ    : num [1:4519] 13 13 12.2 12.2 12.2 ...
 $ iSDA_Depth_to_bedrock: num [1:4519] 197 197 178 178 178 ...
 $ iSDA_SAND_conc       : num [1:4519] 72.1 72.1 83.5 83.5 83.5 ...
 $ iSDA_CLAY_conc       : num [1:4519] 13.59 13.59 8.07 8.07 8.07 ...
 $ iSDA_SILT_conc       : num [1:4519] 12.32 12.32 7.72 7.72 7.72 ...
 $ iSDA_FE_Bulk_dens    : num [1:4519] 140 140 144 144 144 ...
 $ iSDA_log_C_tot       : num [1:4519] 15.52 15.52 3.52 3.52 3.52 ...
 $ iSDA_log_Ca          : num [1:4519] 58.8 58.8 52.5 52.5 52.5 ...
 $ iSDA_log_eCEC        : num [1:4519] 18.7 18.7 14.4 14.4 14.4 ...
 $ iSDA_log_Fe          : num [1:4519] 27.68 27.68 8.88 8.88 8.88 ...
 $ iSDA_log_K           : num [1:4519] 40.2 40.2 35.8 35.8 35.8 ...
 $ iSDA_log_Mg          : num [1:4519] 45.4 45.4 38.6 38.6 38.6 ...
 $ iSDA_log_N           : num [1:4519] 25.5 25.5 12.5 12.5 12.5 ...
 $ iSDA_log_SOC         : num [1:4519] 10.94 10.94 7.43 7.43 7.43 ...
 $ iSDA_log_P           : num [1:4519] 14.48 14.48 4.91 4.91 4.91 ...
 $ iSDA_log_S           : num [1:4519] 8.2 8.2 6.68 6.68 6.68 6.68 6.68 6.68 6.68 6.68 ...
 $ iSDA_pH              : num [1:4519] 59.3 59.3 56 56 56 ...
 $ ASTER_Altitude       : num [1:4519] 202 202 228 228 228 ...
 $ ASTER_Slope          : num [1:4519] 0.49 0.49 0.69 0.69 0.69 0.69 0.69 0.69 0.69 0.69 ...
 $ logRR                : num [1:4519] 0.303 0.316 1.06 1.246 0.918 ...
```

**STEP 2: Splitting data**

```
set.seed(456)

# Splitting data
af.split.wf <- initial_split(ml.data.no.outliers.wf, prop = 0.80, strata = logRR)

af.train.wf <- training(af.split.wf)
af.test.wf <- testing(af.split.wf)
```

**STEP 3: Define resampling techniques on training data**

```
set.seed(345)

# Re-sample technique(s) 

cv.fold.wf <- vfold_cv(af.train.wf, v = 5)
spatial.cv.fold.wf <- spatial_clustering_cv(af.train.wf, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), v = 5)
```

**STEP 4: Define model metrics**

```
# Metrics
multi.metric.wf <- metric_set(rmse, rsq, ccc, mae)

model.control.wf <- control_stack_grid() # save_pred = TRUE, save_workflow = TRUE.
model.control.linear.wf <- control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
```

**STEP 5: Create pre-processing recipies**

```
# Linear model - lm recipe
recipe_base <- 
  recipe(formula = logRR ~ ., data = af.train.wf) %>%
  update_role(Site.Type, new_role = "predictor") %>% # alters an existing role in the recipe to variables.
  update_role(PrName, # or assigns an initial role to variables that do not yet have a declared role.
              Out.SubInd,
              Out.SubInd.Code,
              Product,
              Latitude,
              Longitude,
              Tree,
              new_role = "sample ID") %>%
  step_dummy(Site.Type, one_hot = TRUE, naming = partial(dummy_names,sep = "_")) # convert nominal data into one or more numeric 
 #step_novel(Site.Type, -all_outcomes()) %>% # assign a previously unseen factor level to a new value.


# Prep an juice 
recipe_base %>% prep() %>% juice() %>% glimpse()
```

```
recipe_normal <- recipe_base %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors()) # normalize numeric data: standard deviation of one and a mean of zero.
  
# Prep an juice 
recipe_normal %>% prep() %>% juice() %>% glimpse()
```

```
recipe_corr <- recipe_base %>%
  step_corr(all_predictors()) # remove variables that have large absolute correlations with other variables.

# Warning in cor(x, use = use, method = method) :
#   the standard deviation is zero
# Warning: The correlation matrix has missing values. 3 columns were excluded from the filter.
  
# Prep an juice 
recipe_corr %>% prep() %>% juice() %>% glimpse()
```

```
recipe_remove <- recipe_base %>%
  step_nzv(all_predictors()) %>% # remove variables that are highly sparse and unbalanced.
  step_zv(all_predictors()) # remove variables that contain only a single value.

# Prep an juice 
recipe_remove %>% prep() %>% juice() %>% glimpse()
```

```
recipe_impute_mean <- recipe_base %>%
  step_impute_mean(all_predictors()) # substitute missing values of numeric variables by the training set mean of those variables.

# Prep an juice  
recipe_impute_mean %>% prep() %>% juice() %>% glimpse()
```

```
recipe_impute_knn <- recipe_base %>%
  step_impute_knn(all_predictors(), neighbors = tune()) # substitute missing values of numeric variables by the training set mean of those variables.

# Prep an juice 
# recipe_impute_knn %>% prep() %>% juice() # <- cannot be shown because workflowset will tune this one
```

**STEP 6: Create model specifications**

```
lm_model.wf <- linear_reg() %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("lm") 

glm_model.wf <- linear_reg(
  mode = "regression",
  penalty = tune(),
  mixture = tune()
) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet")

spline_model.wf <- linear_reg() %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("lm") 

knn_model.wf <- nearest_neighbor() %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("kknn") 

# pca_model <- linear_reg() %>% 
#   set_mode("regression") %>% 
#   set_engine("lm") 

svm_model.wf <- svm_poly(cost = tune(),
                         margin = tune()
) %>%
  set_mode("regression") %>%
  set_engine("kernlab")

rf_model.wf <- rand_forest(mtry = tune(),
                        min_n = tune(), 
                        trees = 200
) %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") 
             #importance = "permutation")

xgb_model.wf <- boost_tree(trees = 200, 
                        tree_depth = tune(),
                        min_n = tune(),
                        loss_reduction = tune(), # first three: model complexity
                        sample_size = tune(),    # randomness
                        mtry = tune(),           # randomness
                        learn_rate = tune()      # step size
) %>%    
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("xgboost") 
             #importance = "permutation") 

# catboost_model.wf <- parsnip::boost_tree(      # Remember to load library(treesnip)
#         mode = "regression",
#         trees = tune(),
#         min_n = tune(),
#         learn_rate = tune(),
#         tree_depth = tune()
#     ) %>%
#     set_engine("catboost")
```

**STEP 7: Set up workflowsets**

```
wflwset_setup <- workflow_set(
  preproc = list(
    normalized = recipe_normal,
    rm_corr = recipe_corr, 
    rm_unbalan = recipe_remove, 
    impute_mean = recipe_impute_mean, 
    impute_knn = recipe_impute_knn
  ),
  models = list(
    lm = lm_model.wf,
    glm = glm_model.wf,
    spline = spline_model.wf,
    knn = knn_model.wf,
    svm = svm_model.wf,
    RF = rf_model.wf,
    XGB = xgb_model.wf
    #CatB = catboost_model.wf
  ),
  cross = TRUE
)
```

**STEP 8: Run workflowset**

```
set.seed(579)

if (exists("wflwset_tune_results_cv_2")) rm("wflwset_tune_results_cv_2")

# Initializing parallel processing 
doParallel::registerDoParallel()

# Workflowset tuning

wflwset_tune_results_cv_2 <- wflwset_setup %>%
  workflowsets::workflow_map(
    fn        = "tune_race_anova",
    resamples = cv.fold.wf,
    metrics   = metric_set(rmse, ccc, mae), #
    verbose   = TRUE,
    grid = 15
  )

# Terminating parallel session
parallelStop()
```

Comment: Your chances of getting a helpfuls answer will increase if you trim down your question to a minimal (!) reproducible example. I'd say 90% of your code above is irrelevant to the problem. Trying to trim down your problem will also help you to understand where your problem is, e..g if you leave out a certain step, does the error still occur? If not, this left-out step might tell you what the problem is. If the error still occurs, then it was a good choice to not put it into your example here.

Comment: Please do not edit back "thanks" etc that have been already edited out.

Comment: Showing the output of `str` isn’t that useful `dput` is preferable.

Comment: I got a bit closer to a solution. Now I have only the problem of ```11 of 12 tuning:     impute_knn_RF failed with: Some tuning parameters require finalization but there are recipe parameters that require tuning. Please use `parameters()` to finalize the parameter ranges.
i 12 of 12 tuning:     impute_knn_XGB
x 12 of 12 tuning:     impute_knn_XGB failed with: Some tuning parameters require finalization but there are recipe parameters that require tuning. Please use `parameters()` to finalize the parameter ranges.```

Comment: Does it work without using parallel processing?